# How to synchronise google cloud bucket and instance memory

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have some configuration files in my application, to stop needing a deployment each time the configuration files change - I wanted to have a simple process which would sync these files from a store, such a google cloud storage into a folder on the machine(s) aka RAM.

I need the data in RAM for speed.
I do not want at this stage to add complexity by adding DBs and pub/sub etc.

Running a `nodejs` app on the flexible GAE environment.

In essence I am looking for a simple solution, at this stage.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Cloud Storage FUSE](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) which is a adapter for mounting Cloud Storage buckets to your local machine or GCE instances, as a file system.

You have the installing instructions [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse).

Comment: Thank you, but this is for Google Compute Engine, I was hoping for a solution for Google App Engine - I have found this but it seems not overly clean -> https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/issues/241

Comment: For RAM speed maybe it is better to use API directly. In order to use it with GAE like the solution implies you have to use docker.